# mysqli added empty value on query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Im doing a query that im trying to split into an array like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *FROM questions";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$myString = $row["qID"] . "," . $row["question"] . "," . $row["answer"] . "%";
$myArray = explode('%', $myString);

print_r($myArray);
}

} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

but when i print the array print_r($myArray); or loop trough it my result is as follows:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1,Vem levde mellan 970-1022,2
    [1] =>
)
Array (
    [0] => 2,Vem levde mellan 1008-1050,3
    [1] =>
)
```

why do the arrays retrieve empty values? Each array gets 2 indexes [0] and [1] but the [1] is empty. The [0] index contains the information just the way i want it but that empty index is causing me trouble.

Comment: that is **NOT** mysqli doing it. mysqli is completely out of the picture there. it's you building a string, and exploding it. what is the point of exploding a string you've just built yourself?

Comment: Im splitting them up to handle them in unity for a quiz game :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you explode at the char % and not at the char ,.
I think what you need is:

```
$myArray = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
  $myArray[] = array($row["qID"],$row["question"],$row["answer"]);

print_r($myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

$myString is ending with %.
Then you exlode the string by %. So expected output is array with minimally two indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Just to flesh out my comment above, this is **NOT** mysqli doing anything:

```
php > $x = "a,b,c%";
php > var_dump(explode('%', $x));
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "a,b,c"
  [1]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

This is normal behavior for explode() if the delimiter being used appears at the start OR end of the string.